# React - UI is not updating correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am trying to build user following and followers functionalities using React Context. If logged in user is viewing his own profile then he can see edit / delete button. When he clicks on others profile, follow / unfollow button. The problem is when I click on Follow button, Follow button is being replaced by edit and delete buttons instead of Unfollow button, however if I refresh page at this point, it shows Unfollow correctly.

context file:

```
const initialState = {
  loggedInUser: null,
};

// Add following / follower
  const follow = async (userId, followId) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.put(
        "/api/users/follow",
        { userId, followId },
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
          },
        }
      );
      dispatch({ type: "FOLLOW", payload: res.data });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  // Remove following / follower
  const unfollow = async (userId, unfollowId) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.put(
        "/api/users/unfollow",
        { userId, unfollowId },
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
          },
        }
      );      
      dispatch({ type: "UNFOLLOW", payload: res.data });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

reducer:

```
 case "FOLLOW":
      return {
        ...state,
        loggedInUser: action.payload,
      };
    case "UNFOLLOW":
      return {
        ...state,
        loggedInUser: action.payload,
```

profile

```
// user = profile currently being viewed and it is working fine
{loggedInUser && loggedInUser._id === user._id ? (
                <>
                  <Link to={`/user/edit/${user._id}`} className={classes.link}>
                    <IconButton color="primary">
                      <Edit />
                    </IconButton>
                  </Link>

                  <IconButton onClick={() => handleDelete()}>
                    <Delete color="error" />
                  </IconButton>
                </>
              ) : loggedInUser.following.includes(user._id) ? (
                <Button onClick={() => unfollow(loggedInUser._id, user._id)}>
                  UNFOLLOW
                </Button>
              ) : (
                <Button onClick={() => follow(loggedInUser._id, user._id)}>
                  FOLLOW
                </Button>
              )}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**
Replaced

```
loggedInUser.following.includes(user._id) ? (
                <Button onClick={() => unfollow(loggedInUser._id, user._id)}>
```

with

```
user.followers.some(follower => follower._id === loggedInUser._id) ? (
                <Button onClick={() => unfollow(loggedInUser._id, user._id)}>
                  UNFOLLOW
                </Button>
```

and now I when I click on Follow / Unfollow, edit and delete buttons are not showing, however still I have to refresh page to see the updated UI.

Comment: I see a `<>` as an element block, about the `<Link>` tag.  Is that on purpose?

Comment: what does your `res.data` look like when it returns from the api call.  I feel like the data from the api is manipulating the button choices

Comment: @DJBurb res.data is an object contains details from user model such as name id email following array and followers array, <> is a wrapper for edit and delete button

Comment: I’m pretty sure it’s because your data for loggedInUser or user are messed up. Why don’t you put some console log to check what those values are after click/refresh.

Comment: @hackape you are right. The problem was in reducer. Thank you